# Why does multiplying input by pi in numpy.sin cause it to break?

Tags: python, numpy, pi

I've come across an issue where if I multiply the input of `numpy.sin()` by pi it outputs a strange graph that in no way approximates the actual result. If I round pi to 3.14 it works, but any decimal places up to and including np.pi breaks it. Can anyone tell me what's causing this?

This is my code:

```
lim = 4096
x = np.arange(0,lim)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x) 

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3F42.png) is the output of the plot using `np.pi`, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe3Dp.png) is using 3.14159265, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxDv3.png) is using 3.141, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0O48.png) is using 3.14. As you can see, the amplitude is also screwy, being on the order of -12 for `np.pi`, -5 for 3.14159265, etc. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.sin(x)` expects `x` to be in radians, not degrees.

`2*np.pi*x` in radians is almost precisely an integer multiple of 360 degrees. Its sine is very close to 0, and that is what you see in the first plot.

3.14159265, etc. are even more different from the real Pi than `np.pi`, that is why you start seeing bigger `y`'s. The reason why your plots look like sine waves is because of sampling.

Comment: What a wild demonstration of floating point error. But also, this doesn't totally explain why the plot goes below -1 sometimes, which shouldn't be possible, it seems to me?

Comment: @senderle I guess that's yet another FP error caused by large `x`.

Comment: @senderle Wait, the scale is 1e-12. Everything we see in the first plot are very small numbers.